# willPresent and didReceive Notification delegate not get called when user in foreground and app is installed fresh

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, usernotifications

I have implemented `FirebaseCloudMessaging`, getting `notifications` when the app is in `Background` but when I install the fresh app `willPresent` and `didReceive` Notification `delegate` not get called after 30 to 35 minute it will start calling.

It happens only when I install the app by removing the old one.

Here is my code, you can check where I did mistake

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Register for push notification
        self.registerForNotification()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        return true
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    //MARK: - Register For RemoteNotification
    func registerForNotification() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound]) { granted, error in }
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        #if DEVELOPMENT
            Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
        #else
            Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
        #endif
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        debugPrint("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    //MARK: - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        debugPrint(userInfo)
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        debugPrint(userInfo)
        completionHandler([.badge, .alert, .sound])
    }


    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {

    //MARK: - MessagingDelegate
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print(fcmToken)
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: 30 minutes after installing the app? Or 30 minutes after launching the app? I suppose you know the app must register for push notifications in order to create a new token.

Comment: 30 minutes after installing the app. I receive a notification when an app is in background. the registration process was working fine.

Comment: I mean installing the app is not enough. You have to launch it to call registerForNotification(). And the user must accept when permission request alert appears.

Comment: Is this happening even if you send manual notification from Firebase console?

Comment: @Gabriel, when the app is in background notifications, is received is mean I called registerForNotification()  function and also allowed for permission. thanks.

Comment: @mohit Yes, I tried from push try and firebase console both same issue occurs.

Comment: @HarshadPipaliya the same code is working fine for me, even I change the functions sequence still I'm getting push. Any luck on your side ?

Comment: No, still it is not working. FYI I added GLNotificationBar and Intercom push notification is there any problem with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace registerForNotification function code with this one. May be it will help

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (isAllow, error) in

            if isAllow {

                Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

            }

        }

        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

When user allow the notification then this delegate method will be called

```
 func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        print(fcmToken)



    }
```

when notification is tapped

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        //when notification is tapped

    }
```

This method will be called when app is in foreground

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        //this method is called when notification is about to appear in foreground

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound]) // Display notification as

    }
```

Comment: @HarshadPipaliya .. may be it will work.. Write FirebaseApp.configure() before register for notification.. Also check if you run your app second time it worked or not?